# How Can I Add Automation Id To Syncfusion Chart?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nunit, syncfusion, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to add an automation id to a chart but I can't reach to the elements
I did this:
[image]

like every other element.

but it's not visible to me like you can see in this appium picture:
[image]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

We would like to let you know that current requirement to have a AutomationId support for each and every element (series) in Syncfusion chart considered as feature request since currently have a only support to SfChart.

Since we are already committed with planned work, we will consider this in any of our upcoming releases.

To track its status, please refer the below feedback link
Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/17601

Please cast your vote to make it counts and If you have any more specifications/suggestions to the feature request, you can add it as a comment in the portal.